# About transaction in Realm database

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

This is my `Realm` object:

```
class AchievementDate : Object {

    dynamic var date: Date = Date()
    dynamic var apple: Int = Int(0)

    func save() {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(self)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I change apple's value in View controller's `viewDidLoad()` method, as you can see:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {      
    super.viewDidLoad()
    achievementDate.apple = 2
    achievementDate.save()    
}
```

then I update the apple's value when user clicks the pause button on the screen like this:

```
@IBAction func pausedButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    achievementDate.apple += 1
    achievementDate.save()
}
```

Xcode runs it successfully but when I click the pause button, the app crashes. In the console it says:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call
>   beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

I am quite confused about this, btw, what does transaction mean in general? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A write transaction is used to group modifications of objects within a Realm into a single unit of work. Managed Realm objects may only be modified within a write transaction. The write transaction is scoped to the block you pass to the call to [`Realm.write(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm5writeFzFzT_T_T_). The call to `write` begins a write transaction, the body is executed with the transaction active, and when the block returns the write transaction is committed and the changes are persisted to the Realm file.

You've not shared how `achievementDate` is initialized, but it seems safe to assume based on the exception you're seeing that it is an `AchievementDate` instance that is a managed object (that is, it was either created then added to a Realm, or it was loaded from a Realm). As the exception notes, you can only modify managed objects within a write transaction. You can either expand the scope of your write transaction to encompass the modification of the managed object, or you can avoid modifying a managed object altogether (by adding a primary key to your model class, and using either [`Realm.create(_:value:update:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6createuRxCS_6ObjectrFTMx5valueP_6updateSb_x) or [`Realm.add(_:update:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm3adduRxs8SequenceWx8Iterator7Element_CS_6ObjectrFTx6updateSb_T_) with `update: true` to update an existing object with the given primary key value).

Comment: I initialise the object by declaring a variable as: var achievementDate = AchievementDate() then pass it around the View Controller.

Comment: Btw, how to expand the scope of the write transaction to encompass the modification, how to approach this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That means it starts off life as an unmanaged object, but becomes managed the first time you call `realm.add(self, update: true)` (within `viewDidLoad()`). To expand the scope of the write transaction, you need to move the call to `Realm.write(_:)` out of your `save()` function.

Comment: Any approach to starts off life as a managed object? Advice? Thanks.

Comment: If I move it from my save() function, does it mean I should call in just in the View Controller when it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define a **Primary Key** if you want to update the model:

```
class AchievementDate: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var date:Date = Date()
    dynamic var apple:Int = Int(0)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Then update the model like:

```
static func save(achievementDate:AchievementDate) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(achievementDate, update: true)
    }
}
```

**Alternatively**, if you don't want primary Key, and the model is already retrieved from Realm, you could update the model like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    achievementDate.apple = 2
}
```

Comment: It's not the case that you need to define a primary key in order to update an object. You can retrieve a reference to the object via any supported query and then simply modify its properties within a write transaction.

Comment: @bdash if I define a primary key to update the object, can I understand the primary key actually is the reference of this object in memory? Then retrieve it and update it

Comment: The primary key, if one is declared, is a property on an object that uniquely identifies a given object. Realm provides some convenience functions that can be used with classes that declare a primary key ([`Realm.object(ofType:forPrimaryKey:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6objectu0_RxCS_6ObjectrFT6ofTypeMx13forPrimaryKeyq__GSqx_), and `Realm.create(_:value:update:)` / `Realm.add(_:update:)` with `update: true`).

Comment: @Nan, with  a primary key, you are able to distinguish the object very exactly.

Comment: I followed your first approach, I did modification for the object and update the save() function, Xcode still complains this issue? Quite confused.